# Remove all HTML tags from a html body except <a>, <br>, <b> and <img>

Tags: javascript, html, regex, ecmascript-5

When reading some email HTML body, I often have lots of HTML tags, that I don't want anymore.

How to remove from a string, in Javascript, all HTML tags like:

```
<anything ...>
```

or

```
</anything>
```

except these few cases `<x ...>`, `</x>`, `<x ... />` for `x` being:

- `a`
- `br`
- `b`
- `img`

I thought about something like:

```
s.replace(/<[^a].*>/g, '');
```

but I'm not sure how to do it.

Example:

```
<div id="hello">Hello</div><a href="test">Youhou</a>`
```

should become

```
Hello<a href="test">Youhou</a>
```

**Note**: I'm looking for a few lines-of-code solution that would work for 90% of the times (the email body comes from my own emails, so I didn't include anything malicious), not for a full solution that would require third-party tool/library.

Comment: What of nested elements? Should tags be extracted from divs, or removed, as their parent container is also gone?

Comment: @pkanev `<div id="hello">Hello</div>` should become `Hello`.

Comment: You might want to include that in your description. I was left with the impression you want the tag, *with* its text content gone.

Comment: @pkanev thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<\/?(?!(a|br|b|img)\b)\w+[^>]*>
```

with *nothing*.

`<\/?` Match the start `<`, optionally followed by a `/`

`(?!(a|br|b|img)\b)` Negative look-ahead ensuring we don't match `a`, `br`, `b` or `img` tags.

`\w+[^>]*>` Match the rest of the tag.

[Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/blR7nQ/3).

Comment: Thanks! It works! Here thanks to your `[^>]` it wont take the *very last* `>`  as delimiter of `<hello>foo</hello>hello<test></test>`, but the *very first* one. Is this called non-greedy?

Comment: Would this work too? `<\/?(?!(a|br|b|img)\b)\w+.*?>` I tried and it seems to work. Is it the same?

Comment: You're welcome. Your latter regex is the non-greedy one and will work as well, but may under some circumstances perform porer. `[^>]` simply matches any character **not** being a `>`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't very beautiful but should meet your requirements

```
html.replace(/<\/?([^\s>])[^>]*>/gi,function(tag,tagName){
    return ['a','b','br','img'].indexOf(tagName.toLowerCase()) >= 0? tag: '';
})
```

`\/?` optional slash `([^\s>])` match tagname `[^>]*` attributs spaces ect

Answer (score -1):

You can pass a function as a second parameter to `.replace`, that will decide what to do with the output.

```
str.replace(/<[^a].*>/g, function (s) { /* do something with s */ });
```

See MDN documentation on replace:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Thanks. If possible, could you give a full code here, it's not very easy to know what function to use here.

Comment: you can go with the example in MDN, but basically the match will be replaced with what you return from the function. So you can check, what the matched tag is and return either an empty string or the original tag.

Comment: jeeezz, is it so complicated to toy with the function in your console??
`let a = "acabad"; a.replace(/./g, function(s){ if(s === 'a') return ''; else return s})`