# Clean email HTML body with too many tags

Tags: javascript, html, email, google-apps-script, html-sanitizing

I would like to clean a lot of mails'HTML body which are a bit dirty (taken from Gmail-sent emails): there are lots of nested `<div>`, unwanted changes of fonts, etc.
**I would like to clean this and keep only `<a>`, `<b>`, `<br>`, `<i>`, `<img>`, and nothing else** (and maybe also `<p>` or a few `<div>` if and only if it's really necessary).

With the [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467770/1422096) `/<\/?(?!(a|br|b|img)\b)\w+[^>]*>/g`, it works most of the time:

```js
document.onclick = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<\/?(?!(a|br|b|img)\b)\w+[^>]*>/g, '');
}
```

```html
<div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr">Hello,<div><br></div><div><div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">Thank you for your message.</span><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">If the L<span class="m_-527331299899979m_70391001927gmail-il">orem</span>i</span><span class="m_-527331299899979m_703910001927gmail-m_2466414472930393055gmail-il" style="font-size:12.8px">psum</span><span style="font-size:12.8px"> bla bla </span><a href="http://example.com" style="font-size:12.8px" target="_blank">test</a><span style="font-size:12.8px"> window, then it will be like this.</span><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px">Blah blah.</div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px">Lorem ipsum<span style="font-size:12.8px">lorem ipsum </span><span style="font-size:12.8px">blah blah and</span><span style="font-size:12.8px"> you can </span><span style="font-size:12.8px">also <i>blah blah</i> and finally <i>Blah</i>.</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">-----------</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">Examples:</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test1</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test2</a></span></div><div><br></div><div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test3</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test4</a></span></div></div><div><br></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test4</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test5</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">ex<wbr>ample</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">exam<wbr>ple</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><br></div></div></div><div class="gmail_extra" style="font-size:12.8px"><div class="m_-52733129979m_703911927gmail-m_24664144055gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><span style="font-size:small">Sincerly,</span><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div class="m_-52722719979m_7039100982345401927gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><br></div><div>Myself<br></div><div dir="ltr"><br><b>example</b><br>web: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a><br></div><div>fb: <a href="http://www.facebook.com/example/" target="_blank">www.facebook.com/LoremIp<wbr>sum/</a><br></div><div>mail: <a href="mailto:contact@example.com" target="_blank">contact@example.com</a><br></div><div dir="ltr"><br><img src="http://example.com/example.png"><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><br></div>
```

**(Click anywhere in the email after having run the Code Snippet to see what happens *after* the regex is applied)**

Indeed:

- unuseful tags `<span>` or `</span>` are successfully removed
- `<div fontstyle="...">` and `</div>` are removed

But there is a remaining problem when removing `<div>` like this:

- Empty lines are removed (see empty line between line 1 and 3 of the mail output, between line 3 and 5, etc.)
- The newline is removed after each `example: test1` (see when you run Code Snippet)

I tried to replace `<div.*?><br></div>` by `<br><br>` but it's still not correct.

**Question: How to clean this HTML code, discard the unwanted font changes, etc., and keep the same empty lines, and keep `<a>`, `<b>`, `<br>`, `<i>`, `<img>` tags?**

Note: it has to finally run in a Google Apps Script, so I'm not sure it's possible to import third-party JS libraries...

Comment: Tip: avoid regular expressions to process HTML. Have you tried [HTML tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @Nasha is this available in JS?

Comment: @Nasha Also, a tidy tool won't delete `<br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><br></div>`  at the end of the HTML body (see in the Code Snippet, it's there), but just reindent it correctly, etc. Please correct me if I'm wrong but it won't take the initiative to remove many `<div>` tags, right? Or if so, could you show the output of the HTML body in the code snippet above, with your tidy tool?

Comment: I did use tidy a long long time ago and to my knowledge it can be told to remove as much as you want, especially empty tags — if that's what we're talking about, of course. I've seen tidy at work massively cleaning and tiding a HTML page generated by MS-Word and I was awesomely pleased with the results. It's all I can tell.

Comment: @Nasha Thanks. Did you use a version of it available for JS?

Comment: No, I didn't. At the time I used it from my server-side PHP code. See [Stack Exchange question 3913355](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913355) for a JS approach.

Comment: The actual home page for tidy is [there](http://www.html-tidy.org/).

Comment: @Nasha I tried with tidy.js as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280786/1422096) but it doesn't do much here: it doesn't clean the things like `<div><br></div></div></div>` etc.

Comment: Well, you'll need to tweak the options and find which do the trick. There are quite a few. See version [5.4.0 quick reference](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.4.0.html), you can start from there. Try the [gdoc](http://api.html-tidy.org/tidy/quickref_5.4.0.html#gdoc) option, specific to Google Docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following 5-step process works for the sample you provided:

1. At first passage, keep div tags, but remove all other unwanted tags.
2. Replace `<div><br></div>` with `<br><br>`
3. Replace any sequence of 1 or more closing `</div>` tags, possibly preceded by `<br>`, with a single `<br>`.
4. Remove all div tags.
5. Replace any sequence of 2 or more `<br>` rags with two `<br>` tags.

Code:

```js
document.onclick = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
                              .replace(/<\/?(?!(a|br|b|i|img|div)\b)\w+[^>]*>/g, '')
                              .replace(/<div[^>]*><br><\/div>/g, '<br><br>')
                              .replace(/((<br>)?<\/div>)+/g, '<br>')
                              .replace(/<div[^>]*>/g, '')
                              .replace(/(<br>){2,}/g, '<br><br>');
}
```

```html
<div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr">Hello,<div><br></div><div><div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">Thank you for your message.</span><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">If the L<span class="m_-527331299899979m_70391001927gmail-il">orem</span>i</span><span class="m_-527331299899979m_703910001927gmail-m_2466414472930393055gmail-il" style="font-size:12.8px">psum</span><span style="font-size:12.8px"> bla bla </span><a href="http://example.com" style="font-size:12.8px" target="_blank">test</a><span style="font-size:12.8px"> window, then it will be like this.</span><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px">Blah blah.</div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px">Lorem ipsum<span style="font-size:12.8px">lorem ipsum </span><span style="font-size:12.8px">blah blah and</span><span style="font-size:12.8px"> you can </span><span style="font-size:12.8px">also <i>blah blah</i> and finally <i>Blah</i>.</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">-----------</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">Examples:</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test1</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test2</a></span></div><div><br></div><div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test3</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test4</a></span></div></div><div><br></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test4</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test5</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">ex<wbr>ample</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">exam<wbr>ple</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><br></div></div></div><div class="gmail_extra" style="font-size:12.8px"><div class="m_-52733129979m_703911927gmail-m_24664144055gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><span style="font-size:small">Sincerly,</span><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div class="m_-52722719979m_7039100982345401927gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><br></div><div>Myself<br></div><div dir="ltr"><br><b>example</b><br>web: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a><br></div><div>fb: <a href="http://www.facebook.com/example/" target="_blank">www.facebook.com/LoremIp<wbr>sum/</a><br></div><div>mail: <a href="mailto:contact@example.com" target="_blank">contact@example.com</a><br></div><div dir="ltr"><br><img src="http://example.com/example.png"><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><br></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michelle! It nearly works, except that `example: test1 <linebreak>example: test2` then goes into the same line... That's tricky for this one. Any idea?

Comment: I edited to bring it closer to the target. It's not going to be perfect, as other said regex is a blunt tool to use with HTML.

Comment: Nearly perfect :) There's just one final guilty tag @Michelle: `<div>Hello<br></div><div>Another div</div>` should produce no empty line, and with the current code, it does.

Comment: Tweaked further but hope you take initiative from here on, because it's your data set. My point was that several stages of replacement can process text more accurately than one step. But whatever the regex construction is, it's probably going to break on another message which will have a `<table>` or something like that in it.

Comment: Perfect now @Michelle!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally use (working for all emails sent via Gmail), credits go 99,99% to @Michelle's accepted answer:

```js
document.onclick = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<\/?(?!(a|br|b|i|img|div)\b)\w+[^>]*>/g, '')
             .replace(/<div[^>]*><br[^>]*>/g, '<br><br>')
             .replace(/((<br>)?<\/div>)+/g, '<br>')
             .replace(/<div[^>]*>/g, '')
             .replace(/(<br>){2,}/g, '<br><br>')
             .replace(/ style="font-size.*?"/g, ''); 
}
```

```html
<div dir="ltr"><div class="gmail_quote"><div dir="ltr">Hello,<div><br></div><div><div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">Thank you for your message.</span><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">If the L<span class="m_-527331299899979m_70391001927gmail-il">orem</span>i</span><span class="m_-527331299899979m_703910001927gmail-m_2466414472930393055gmail-il" style="font-size:12.8px">psum</span><span style="font-size:12.8px"> bla bla </span><a href="http://example.com" style="font-size:12.8px" target="_blank">test</a><span style="font-size:12.8px"> window, then it will be like this.</span><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px">Blah blah.</div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><br></div><div style="font-size:12.8px">Lorem ipsum<span style="font-size:12.8px">lorem ipsum </span><span style="font-size:12.8px">blah blah and</span><span style="font-size:12.8px"> you can </span><span style="font-size:12.8px">also <i>blah blah</i> and finally <i>Blah</i>.</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">-----------</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px">Examples:</span></div><div style="font-size:12.8px"><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test1</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test2</a></span></div><div><br></div><div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test3</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test4</a></span></div></div><div><br></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test4</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">test5</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">ex<wbr>ample</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">example</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px">example: <a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">exam<wbr>ple</a></span></div><div><span style="font-size:12.8px"><br></span></div><div><br></div></div></div><div class="gmail_extra" style="font-size:12.8px"><div class="m_-52733129979m_703911927gmail-m_24664144055gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><div dir="ltr"><span style="font-size:small">Sincerly,</span><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div><div><div class="m_-52722719979m_7039100982345401927gmail_signature"><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><div><div dir="ltr"><br></div><div>Myself<br></div><div dir="ltr"><br><b>example</b><br>web: <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">www.example.com</a><br></div><div>fb: <a href="http://www.facebook.com/example/" target="_blank">www.facebook.com/LoremIp<wbr>sum/</a><br></div><div>mail: <a href="mailto:contact@example.com" target="_blank">contact@example.com</a><br></div><div dir="ltr"><br><img src="http://example.com/example.png"><br></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><br></div>
```